# Remove hastag/pound/octothorpe from string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string which has a hastag/pound/octothorpe in it, and want it removed using a regex expression.

e.g.

```
iii <- '#lkdjljf, lkdflsdkf'
```

i would like a `gsub(regex_bit_here,'',iii)`

to remove the hastag/pound/octothorpe

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific about your inputs and desired outputs. You're an experienced SO denizen, so this shld not come as a surprise request.

Comment: What did you try? You don't need any regex magic; just give it the literal you want to select, and what you want to replace it with. `sub`/`gsub`, `fixed = TRUE` or not, it should all work: `sub('#', '', '#lkdjljf, lkdflsdkf')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried`gsub("^#",'',iii)`, and it works